# Asana restfull API returns code 434: Client Error

Tags: asana, asana-api

In a Windows Forms .Net 4.5 app, calling Asana's RESTfull end points to get projects or users return error code 434, which is not documented. All it says is "Client Error". Tried both basic and bearer authentication using ApiKey or personal key (respectively), all with same results. The account is set OK for API access, as trying through Postman in Chrome works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

TLS 1.0 was recently turned off in Asana. You may start looking there https://asana.com/developers/feed/tls-10-shutoff

Comment: You're spot on. We return error code 434 when you're using a deprecated version of TLS.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. We are using .net 4.5. Any idea how to make it use a newer version of TLS?

Answer (score 1):

OK, found it.

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

before making any connection does the trick.

Thanks for the responses. May I suggest to add the details of 434 error code to the Asana API docs?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the [Asana 434 error code](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors) is now in the docs